# Problema ao instalar módulo HiRedis

Tags: node.js, npm, redis

Estava instalando o módulo [npm Hiredis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hiredis), mas tive problemas. Segundo sua documentação, o único pré-requisito necessário é a presença do **Python 2.7** e do **gcc / g++ 4.8**, os quais já possuo.

> This requires:
>
> - gcc / g++ 4.8 or newer.
> - python 2.7 or any newer 2.x version. python 3.x is not supported.

Mas mesmo assim não consigo êxito em instalá-lo.

Já instalei o módulo oficial do Redis e o próprio DB, e ambos funcionam normalmente, só estou tendo problemas com o HiRedis.

Segue erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Desde já, agradeço.

Comment: Tive um problema parecido onde conseguia instalar em ambiente Mac mas não em Window, com o `node-gyp`. Talvez já tenhas visto, mas dá uma olhada aqui: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33183161/node-gyp-error-tracker-error-trk0005-failed-to-locate-cl-exe-the-system-c

Comment: @Sergio, já tinha feito isso com a minha versão do MSVS 2015, mas seu link me ajudou com as outras respostas e comentários, que após seguir alguns passos, consegui resolver o problema. Obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema com os seguintes passos:

- Rodei isso no prompt:

  ```
  set GYP_MSVS_VERSION=2015
  npm config set msvs_version 2015 --global
  ```
- Criei um arquivo Project Visual C++ no Visual Studio 2015
- Instalei tudo o que pedia (C++, Windows SDK, etc)
- Executei o prompt como ADM  e rodei o comando de instalação do módulo novamente.

Deu certo!